# Find the eigenvalues of T and an ordered basis β for Mat 2×2(R) such that [T]β is a diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Really been stuck on this question for a while now, help would be  appreciated!

Ps: No clue how to properly format this question lol

Let $T:\Bbb R^{2\times 2}\to \Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ be a linear transformation defined by $T(A)=A^T$. Find the eigenvalues of $T$ and an ordered basis $\beta$ for $\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ such that $[T]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: You want to find an eigenvector of this linear transformation, right? This mean we need to find a non-zero vector $A$ so that $T(A) = \lambda A$ but $T(A) = A^T$. What can you say about $T^2(A)$?

Comment: For formatting, consult this website: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real numbers $a,b,c,d$, the linear transformation is: $T\left(\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}a & c \\ b & d\end{bmatrix}$. You could find the matrix corresponding to the standard basis, and then use the characteristic polynomial to find the eigenvalues, but this transformation makes if fairly obvious that the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=1$ (symmetric matrices) and $\lambda_2=-1$ (skew-symmetric matrices). The linearly independent $2\times 2$ symmetric matrices are $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$; these are the eigenvectors for $\lambda_1$ (note they could be any nonzero real multiple of what I have). The only $2\times 2$ skew-symmetric matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$; this is the eigenvector for $\lambda_2$ (again, a nonzero scalar multiple of this also works). So you have $4$ linearly independent eigenvectors over a $4$-dimensional domain and codomain (so it is diagonalizable). The diagonal basis thus corresponds to a basis consisting of eigenvectors, and the matrix is one consisting of the eigenvalues on the diagonal (in order of the corresponding basis eigenvectors).

Comment: Thank you for this,it really helped!!!